# MPI communicator error

Tags: c++, mpi, parallel-processing

I had a problem with a program that uses MPI and I have just fixed it, however, I don't seem to understand what was wrong in the first place. I'm quite green with programming relates stuff, so please be forgiving.

The program is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <mpi.h>

#define RNumber     3

using namespace std;

int main() {
    /*Initiliaze MPI*/
    int     my_rank;    //My process rank
    int         comm_sz;    //Number of processes
    MPI_Comm    GathComm;   //Communicator for MPI_Gather
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_sz);

    /*Initialize an array for results*/
    long rawT[RNumber];
    long * Times = NULL;        //Results from threads
    if (my_rank == 0) Times = (long*) malloc(comm_sz*RNumber*sizeof(long));

    /*Fill rawT with results at threads*/
    for (int i = 0; i < RNumber; i++) {
        rawT[i] = i;
    }


    if (my_rank == 0) {
        /*Main thread recieves data from other threads*/
        MPI_Gather(rawT, RNumber, MPI_LONG, Times, RNumber, MPI_LONG, 0, GathComm);

    }
    else {
        /*Other threads send calculation results to main thread*/
        MPI_Gather(rawT, RNumber, MPI_LONG, Times, RNumber, MPI_LONG, 0, GathComm);
    }

    /*Finalize MPI*/
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
};
```

On execution the program returns the following message:

> Fatal error in PMPI_Gather: Invalid communicator, error stack:
>   PMPI_Gather(863): MPI_Gather(sbuf=0xbf824b70, scount=3, MPI_LONG,
>   rbuf=0x98c55d8, rcount=3, MPI_LONG, root=0, comm=0xe61030) failed
>   PMPI_Gather(757): Invalid communicator Fatal error in PMPI_Gather:
>   Invalid communicator, error stack: PMPI_Gather(863):
>   MPI_Gather(sbuf=0xbf938960, scount=3, MPI_LONG, rbuf=(nil), rcount=3,
>   MPI_LONG, root=0, comm=0xa6e030) failed PMPI_Gather(757): Invalid
>   communicator

After I remove `GathComm` altogether and substitute it with `MPI_COMM_WORLD` default communicator everything works fine.

Could anyone be so kind to explain what was I doing wrong and how did this adjustment made everything work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `GathComm` has not been assigned a valid communicator. "`MPI_Comm GathComm;`" only declares the variable to hold a communicator but doesn't create one.

You can use the default communicator (`MPI_COMM_WORLD`) if you simply want to include all procs in the operation.

Custom communicators are useful when you want to organised your procs in separate groups or when using [virtual communication topologies.](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-11-html/node129.html#Node129)

To find out more, check out [this article](http://www.clustermonkey.net/content/view/52/2/) which describes Groups, Communicator and Topologies.